# Swift / iOS - Preserve UINavigationItem when pushing new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Is there a clean way in swift 4 to preserve the exact same `UINavigationItems` in the navigation bar that is presented when pushing from one UIViewController to the other.

This means I want the navigation bar to stay exactly as it is (with all the same items) when a new view controller is pushed on to the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its there for a long time. Just setting the rootViewController or currentVC  as the delegate of the UINavigationBar.

```
 class RootVC :  UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate{


   func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPush item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool{
    return false;
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.delegate = self
}}
```